# Foreach with eloquent in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to loop through the items using eloquent in laravel but I'm getting `0`. Please see my code below.

**Model**

```
Class Store{

    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
$products_count = 0;

foreach($store->products() as $product)
{
   if($product->status == 1)
   {
     $products_count++;
   }
}

dd($products_count);
```

Note: I have data in my database.

Comment: You can check my updated answer based on `$product->status == 1` condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `$store->products()` returns an eloquent collection which doesn't contain the data from the database yet. You need to do `$store->products` instead.

If you need to get the count from the database then use

```
$store->products()->where('status', 1)->count()
```

Comment: Is this the same with belongsToMany()? Coz sometimes the relationship (e.g. $store->products()) is working. I'm confuse with this.

Comment: @Jonjie it is the same for all the relationships in Laravel

Comment: @Jonjie there is the updated answer to get the count of the conditionalized products

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `withCount` method something like that

**Controller**

```
$stores = Store::withCount('products')->get();
or
$store = Store::where('id', 1)->withCount('products')->first();
```

`WithCount` on the particular status

```
$stores = Store::withCount(['products' => function ($query) {
                            $query->where('status', 1);
                          }
                    ])
                    ->get();
```

ref: [withcount on relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55390530/how-to-get-relationship-counts-without-loading-objects-in-laravel/55390594#55390594)

Answer (score 2):

With the function-annotation (i.e. `products()`) you are retrieving the `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`-instance, not the actual Eloquent-collection.

Instead, you would have to use `$store->products` – then you will get retrieve the related collection.

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel `$store->products()` makes you access the QueryBuilder instance, instead there is the Laravel way of doing `$store->products`, which loads the QueryBuilder and retrieves the collection automatically and down the line is easy to optimise.